# Ionic Allow location all the time API level 29

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-location, ionic-native

I'm trying to use API level 29 on my ionic app, and I require the app to ask the user for "Allow all the time" location. I've added all the suggested modifications.

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION">
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION">
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERMISSION.FOREGROUND_SERVICE">
```

My app.component.ts:

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.setProviders();
      this.checkBackgroundPermission();
    });
  }

private async checkBackgroundPermission() {
    try {
      const result = await this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
      if (!result || result.hasPermission === false) {
        this.requestPermissions();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.requestPermissions();
    }
  }

 private async requestPermissions() {
    try {
      const data = await this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([
        this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
        this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION,
        this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.FOREGROUND_SERVICE
      ]);
      if (!data.hasPermission) {
        throw new Error('No permission');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      await this.alertService.showAlert(
        'Background location',
        'We need background location access in order to continue.'
      );
      this.signOut();
    }
```

However when I target Api Level 29 it doesn't show the request for allow location all the time.

[image: allthetime]

But if I use Api Level 28 it shows the permission I need

Any suggestions to make this work?

Comment: Since I'm using `ionic-native/background-geolocation` it breaks when the user doesn't allow location all the time.

Comment: Having the exact same issue.

Comment: Any luck with getting the prompt to be "All the time ?"

Comment: No, I'm gonna try with David Buck answer bellow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. The following worked for me.

1. Use the AndroidPermissions to request the following permissions.

   ```
   const data = await this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([
           "android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION",
           "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
           this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
   ]);
   ```

Note the string `"android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"`, instead of `this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`, which is actually undefined during runtime. My guess is that the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission didn't exist when the `AndroidPermissions` plugin was released.

2. Call the `requestPermissions` method before Background Location. This is very important.
3. Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />` to platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Now I need get location in background

Answer (score 0):

At the place where you are calling check permission for ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, also check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and if any of them is not found, call your requestPermissions method. This should help.

Answer (score 0):

1. add this to `platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

2. change in `Geolocation.java` file (geolocation plugin)

- delete :

```
String [] permissions = { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }
```

- replace it with :

```
String [] permissions = { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,  Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION };
```